# "Have not went" or "have not gone"

Tags: word-choice, simple-past-as-past-participle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the incorrect phrase “should have went” so widely used?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31142/why-is-the-incorrect-phrase-should-have-went-so-widely-used)

Which is correct?

> If you haven't **went** out to see the moon tonight, you should.
>
> If you haven't **gone** out to see the moon tonight, you should.

Comment: Check out the [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/31454/300) this has been closed as a duplicate of. *Gone* is standard English, but *went* can be grammatical depending on dialect and register.

Comment: http://www.antimoon.com/forum/t13272.htm