# "Overrode" vs "Overridden"

Tags: verbs, past-tense, past-participles, simple-past, simple-past-as-past-participle

I got into an argument about the sentence "Have you overrode SomeThingamajig?"

I thought that "have overrode" is incorrect, and should be "overrode" or "have overridden", or perhaps "did override".

However, I was told that in some contexts, "have overrode" is appropriate.

Is "Have you overrode SomeThingamajig?" correct?

When is is appropriate to say "have overrode"?

Comment: Never heard that myself, but [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/override#Usage_notes) has some interesting figures. "*Overrode* is sometimes used as past participle instead of *overridden*. It seems more common in the US. It seems most common with *had*, reaching 20% of usage in Usenet with that auxiliary. Less common was use with *have* and least with *has*.
Usage in edited works seems consistently less than 2% with most auxiliaries, except *had* where it can approach 5% of usage."

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA Wonder if that's about as common as "have ate", "have roden", and such.

Comment: What about 'overwritten'? 'overwrote'? Which is the eggcorn?

Comment: @Kendall: What MetaEd only hints at is that "have ate" is indeed grammatical in several US Northeast dialects. Though even there, if I am not mistaken, it is more commonly triggered not by *have* alone, but rather by *coulda/shoulda/woulda*, or in negations (i.e. "haven't ate"). We actually have a question on "should have went" with a [rather helpful answer by a linguist](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/31454). So while John Lawler (who is a linguist himself) is certainly 100% correct for Standard English you might wish to check if the folks you are arguing with are from NJ or Long Island.

Comment: "Have overrode" may be appropriate in some minority varieties of English. If the variety allows "have ate", "have went", "have did", or "have saw", then "have overrode" would also be fine. But not in standard English.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

*Override* is formed from the irregular verb *ride*.

The Principal Parts of *ride* are ***ride, rode, ridden***.

That means the PPs of *override* are ***override, overrode, overridden***. 
With me so far?

OK, the first PP in each case is the **Infinitive** form (*to ride, to override*).

The second PP is the **Past** form (*They rode it, They overrode it*)

The third PP is the **Perfect Passive Participle** (*They have ridden it, They have overridden it*).

The Perfect Passive Participle is the verb form that one uses with *be* in the Passive construction, and -- as here -- with *have* in the Perfect construction. One does not use the Past Tense verb form with an auxiliary verb in **any** construction.

***Executive Summary:*** **Was overrode,* **has overrode,* and **be overrode* are **all** ungrammatical.

Comment: So, the answers to my questions are "no" and "never"?

Comment: Yes, I think you could draw those respective conclusions.

Comment: So what @RegDwightAAA mentions in his comment above (about Wikipedia indicating *overrode* as a possible past participle in certain cases) is totally nonsense? I tend to trust you and grammar books more than Wikipedia, but have you got anything to  support your statement?

Comment: ***I*** didn't say it's totally nonsense. It's a regional dialect; these often have variants of irregular forms; and it's a common tendency for all English verbs to have the same forms in Past and Past Participle. All regular verbs do, and so do many irregular verbs (e.g, _think, thought, thought; wring, wrung, wrung_).

Comment: You're right, you said that *was overrode*, *has overrode* and *be overrode* are **all** ungrammatical, it's me who summarized it as *totally nonsense*. I suppose the meaning is different, but perhaps you have to take into account the fact that foreigners tend to learn what is proper and grammatical, whereas *ungrammatical regional forms* are usually avoided as not worth bothering with.

Comment: Yea, except this site does not distinguish between native speakers and non-native speakers, and as for "foreigners", unless somebody mentions their location in a question or an answer, we have no idea where people are or what languages they're speaking. I.e, we're all foreigners, and who knows what nonsense we've been taught?

Comment: When am I intended to use overridden, and when overrode?

Comment: Use _overridden_ where a past participle is required, and _overrode_ where a past tense form is required. The same as _ridden_ and _rode_, _sung_ and _sang_, _overeaten_ and _overate_, etc.

Comment: +1. But imo you should rephrase the executive summary. My teacher used to say that errors/"don't do"s should not be written down.

Comment: @mike Your teacher was wrong. You have to write down the ungrammatical ones so you know them and can see what rules they violated. That's how rules are discovered in the first place -- when they fail.

Answer (score 0):

Overrode is correct.  Examples are are as follows:

The pain was so intense that it overrode all of the other pain."  It didn't "was overrode," or did not "override," it "overrode."

The Supreme Court ruling of 2017 overrode all previous Appellate Court rulings on this subject.

Overrode is the past participle of the irregular verb override, and the same irregular verbs tense of ride, rode, have/has/had overridden.

Comment: In "The pain was so intense that it overrode all of the other pain," "overrode" is a simple past tense form, not a past participle. The past participle is the form of the verb that is used after "have/has/had" to form the perfect.

Comment: Most of this answer is very difficult to decipher, but to the extent that it’s understandable, it is incorrect. _Overrode_ is not the past participle of _override_ except in certain dialects. Restricting it to past tense use is highly advisable and certain to avoid anyone thinking it sounds wrong.